# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and I'm trying execute this code but it show me this message 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO"

```
<?php
include "../conexao.php";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT vale_alimentacao FROM usuario WHERE  id=1");
$ln = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$vale_alimentacao = $ln['vale_alimentacao'];

$total_diario = 0.0;
$contador = 0.0;

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, data, valor_almoco, bebida FROM vale_alimentacao WHERE 1=1");
while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
            $contador = 0.0;

            if($ln['valor_almoco'] < 8.0)
                $contador = $ln['valor_almoco'];
            else if($ln['valor_almoco'] > 8.0 && $ln['valor_almoco'] < 13.0)
                $contador = 8.0;
            else
                $contador = ($ln['valor_almoco']-8.0);´

            echo $contador;

            $total_diario += $contador;
?>
```

Anyone can help me? It is syntax error but I dont get where is.
Hugs

Comment: How to find this yourself: look for every _echo_ in your code and check the line before that.

Comment: Or look at the line number given in the error and check on or before that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `´` in the line

```
$contador = ($ln['valor_almoco']-8.0);´
```

To debug such errors look at the line number in the error message. It helps.

Comment: I swear, I thougth that this char was a dead pixel in my monitor. LOL

Answer (score 0):

```
$contador = ($ln['valor_almoco']-8.0);´
```

Has a ` at the end.